# Pandas: how to sum by groupby value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, multi-index

Using this:

```
ipl_data = {'Team': ['Riders', 'Riders', 'Devils', 'Devils', 'Kings',
         'Kings', 'Kings', 'Kings', 'Riders', 'Royals', 'Royals', 'Riders'],
         'Rank': [1, 2, 2, 3, 3,4 ,1 ,1,2 , 4,1,2],
         'Points':[876,789,863,673,741,812,756,788,694,701,804,690]}
df = pd.DataFrame(ipl_data)

df.groupby(['Team',"Rank"]).sum()
```

This is returned.

```
             Points
Team   Rank        
Devils 2        863
       3        673
Kings  1       1544
       3        741
       4        812
Riders 1        876
       2       2173
Royals 1        804
       4        701
```

How you I extract values (Points) where rank equals '1', so 1544+ 876+ 804. 
and the same for rank equals 2, and 3.

Comment: What is the exact output that you want? One data frame per rank value, or a single data frame with sum per rank sorted somehow?

Comment: df  with sum per rank sorted somehow, I want to see , then sum the values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe need [`DataFrame.xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html):

```
print (df.xs(1, level=1))

        Points
Team          
Kings     1544
Riders     876
Royals     804

print (df.xs(2, level=1))

        Points
Team          
Devils     863
Riders    2173
```

For select by multiple criteria use [slicers](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers):

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
print (df.loc[idx[:, [1,2]], :])

             Points
Team   Rank        
Devils 2        863
Kings  1       1544
Riders 1        876
       2       2173
Royals 1        804
```

---

```
print (df.loc[idx['Riders', [1,2]], :])

             Points
Team   Rank        
Riders 1        876
       2       2173
```

---

If want sum all groups by `Rank`s change grouping columns from `['Team',"Rank"]` to `Rank`:

```
s = df.groupby("Rank")['Points'].sum()
print (s)
Rank
1    3224
2    3036
3    1414
4    1513
Name: Points, dtype: int64
```

If need also `df1` then use `sum` per `level=1`:

```
df1 = df.groupby(['Team',"Rank"]).sum()
print (df1)
             Points
Team   Rank        
Devils 2        863
       3        673
Kings  1       1544
       3        741
       4        812
Riders 1        876
       2       2173
Royals 1        804
       4        701

s1 = df1.sum(level=1)
print (s1)
      Points
Rank        
2       3036
3       1414
1       3224
4       1513
```

Comment: @Merlin - Yes, use `level='Rank'` like `df1.sum(level='Rank')`

Answer (score 1):

One option

```
>>> df_group = df.groupby(['Team',"Rank"]).sum().reset_index()
     Team  Rank  Points
0  Devils     2     863
1  Devils     3     673
2   Kings     1    1544
3   Kings     3     741
4   Kings     4     812
5  Riders     1     876
6  Riders     2    2173
7  Royals     1     804
8  Royals     4     701
```

and now you can just filter on `'Rank'`:

```
>>> df_group.loc[df_group['Rank']==1,'Points']
2    1544
5     876
7     804
```

Another options is grouping by Rank again and then aggregating as a list:

```
>>> df.groupby(['Team','Rank']).sum().reset_index().groupby('Rank')['Points'].agg(lambda x: list(x))
Rank
1    [1544, 876, 804]
2         [863, 2173]
3          [673, 741]
4          [812, 701]
```

Or maybe you just wanted to sort by rank, it's hard to tell because you haven't provided a desired output:

```
>>> df.groupby(['Team','Rank']).sum().reset_index().sort_values('Rank')
     Team  Rank  Points
2   Kings     1    1544
5  Riders     1     876
7  Royals     1     804
0  Devils     2     863
6  Riders     2    2173
1  Devils     3     673
3   Kings     3     741
4   Kings     4     812
8  Royals     4     701
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df[df['Rank'] == 1] # Filter by rank before summing
```

Answer (score 1):

I like using the [`axis` argument in .loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers):

```
df.groupby(['Team',"Rank"]).sum().loc(axis=0)[:,1]
```

Output:

```
             Points
Team   Rank        
Kings  1       1544
Riders 1        876
Royals 1        804
```

Or

```
df.groupby(['Team',"Rank"]).sum().loc(axis=0)[:,2]

             Points
Team   Rank        
Devils 2        863
Riders 2       2173
```

Or as @Jezrael has done without `pd.Slicers`:

```
df.groupby(['Team',"Rank"]).sum().loc(axis=0)[:,[1,2]]

             Points
Team   Rank        
Devils 2        863
Kings  1       1544
Riders 1        876
       2       2173
Royals 1        804
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reorder by the rank after summing:

```
import pandas as pd

ipl_data = {'Team': ['Riders', 'Riders', 'Devils', 'Devils', 'Kings',
         'Kings', 'Kings', 'Kings', 'Riders', 'Royals', 'Royals', 'Riders'],
         'Rank': [1, 2, 2, 3, 3,4 ,1 ,1,2 , 4,1,2],
         'Points':[876,789,863,673,741,812,756,788,694,701,804,690]}
df = pd.DataFrame(ipl_data)

result = df.groupby(['Team', 'Rank']).sum().swaplevel().sort_index()
# Or just:
result = df.groupby(['Rank', 'Team']).sum()

print(result)
```

Output:

```
Rank Team
1    Kings     1544
     Riders     876
     Royals     804
2    Devils     863
     Riders    2173
3    Devils     673
     Kings      741
4    Kings      812
     Royals     701
```

Answer (score 1):

May be you can try swapping columns in `groupby` to `["Rank", "Team"]`:

```
grouped = df.groupby(["Rank", "Team"]).sum()
print(grouped)
```

Result:

```
             Points
Rank Team          
1    Kings     1544
     Riders     876
     Royals     804
2    Devils     863
     Riders    2173
3    Devils     673
     Kings      741
4    Kings      812
     Royals     701
```

Then, to get sum for any rank, you can use `loc`. For e.g. for first rank would be:

```
grouped.loc[1].Points.sum()
```

Result:

```
3224
```